# `position:absolute` not being positioned wrt to first ancestor element and not following any observable pattern either

Tags: html, css

[figma.com](https://www.figma.com/file/12aCPysPYYkU0YrhjdOS7e/CovidGuide?node-id=3%3A4)

I'm trying to create a website similar to the prototype given in Figma (linked above). This is the code I used:

```
<div class="Tips" id="Tips">
        <div id="TipsHeading"> Tips
        </div>
        <div class="rec2">
            <img id="img1" src="personal.png">
            <div id="WearMask"> Wear Mask </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Tips{background: #FFFFFF;
top: 1024px;}


#TipsHeading{position: absolute;
height: 66px;
top: 1053px;}

.rec2{position: absolute;
height: 369px;
top: 1192px;}

#WearMask{position: absolute;
top: 160px;}

#img1{position: absolute;
left: 24.85%;
right: 26.5%;
top: 49.36%;
bottom: 10.7%;
height: 278px;
width: 338px;}
```

I'm using the id property for both "TipsHeading" and "WearMask". However `TipsHeading` is position wrt the top of the page, and `WearMask` is positioned wrt to `.rec2`. It doesn't make sense to me.

This has happened multiple times and it's becoming very difficult for me to debug my code, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) says about position absolute:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created >for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest >positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial >containing block.

`position: absolute` also reinitialises the position of its children like `position: relative` does.

In your case, `TipsHeading`is positioned based on its closest positioned ancestor `.Tips`, whereas `#WearMask` is positioned based on the position of its ancestor `.rec2`

That being said, giving all your elements an absolute positioning will create a lot of mess in your css. Try to work with relative elements while using `flex`,`margin` and `padding` instead.

Comment: yes...except `TipsHeading` is NOT positioned wrt to `.Tips`, it's position wrt to the tops of the page. That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: * top not "tops"

Comment: add this:

```.Tips {
  position: relative;
}```

Comment: I have some doubts in how relative works, so I didn't use it. Do I need to know the position the element would've been in static to use relative. Like how is this Tage different from absolute?

Comment: No you dont need to know the position of the element. Actually you rarely need to use `top`/ `right` / `bottom` /  `left`.
I would suggest you watch some tutorials on how to style a web page as it is out of scope and not a subject that can be explained in just some lines.

Answer (score 1):

The element in `position: absolute` is positioned relative to its first positioned ancestor element.